# Para que serve um scope no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Vi na documentação do Laravel uma explanação sobre a utilização do Eloquent. Lá eu vi uma parte onde fala sobre [Local and Global Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#local-scopes).

Como não domino muito o inglês, fiquei com algumas dúvidas quanto ao uso.

- Para que serve esses métodos onde definimos o prefixo `scope` nos models?
- Qual é a diferença entre Local e Global scope?

Exemplo da documentação (local scope):

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Scope a query to only include popular users.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopePopular($query)
    {
        return $query->where('votes', '>', 100);
    }
}
```

Exemplo documentação (global scope):

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('age', function(Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('age', '>', 200);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

- Para que serve esses métodos onde definimos o prefixo scope nos `models`?

Tem a finalidade de facilitar rotinas de consultas no seu [model (Eloquent)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent), trazendo funcionalidades prévias de consultas `SQL`, ajudando, então, no  desenvolvimento e padronização de consultas. É divido em [Global Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes) ou [Local Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes).

---

- Qual é a diferença entre Local e Global scope?

[Global Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes) limita ou restringe o seu `model` a executar filtros prévios `(where, order by)` em todas as consultas `SQL` de um determinado [model (Eloquent)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent). Seria uma padronização para esse `model` que na execução de consultas tenham esse filtro. Um exemplo claro é a exclusão de um determinado registro onde o determinante é uma data com o valor `null` a consulta traz o registro, diferente de `null` o registro não aparece, seguindo a lógica do [soft-deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#soft-deleting).

***Exemplo:***

```
namespace App;    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;    
class Cliente extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

No caso acima se codificar `Cliente::all()`, trará a lista de todos os clientes que não foram excluídos, porque, o [Global Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes)  do `traits SoftDeletes` tem um filtro restritivo e global a todas as consultas (`select * from clientes where deleted_at is null`). Se por acaso quiser trazer todos os registros inclusive os excluídos faça o comando `Cliente::withTrashed()->get()`, sendo uma forma elegante de burlar esse [Global Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes). Uma forma radical de elimitar todos os [Global Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes) seria assim `Cliente::withoutGlobalScopes()->get()`.

Já no [Local Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes) é um filtro preparado, ou atalho, que só é executado mediante chamada do método, sendo diferente do [Global Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes) que é sempre chamado de forma automática e transparente. Tem as mesmas características, mas a forma de invocação é o que difere.

**Exemplo:**

```
namespace App;    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;    
class Cliente extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function scopeStatus($query)
    {
        return $query->where('status', 1);
    }

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

}
```

Existe nesse `model` Cliente um `scopeStatus` que eu defini um filtro onde `status = 1`, mas, eu preciso invocá-lo para que ele passe a ser executado e a consulta receba mais esse filtro.

```
Cliente::status()->get(); 
//SQL => select * from cliente where `status = 1`
```

se eu colocar simplesmente:

```
Cliente::all(); 
//SQL => select * from cliente
```

a SQL não terá o filtro, ou seja, o [Local Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes) precisa ser invocado para funcionar.

*Mesmo com [Global Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes) e [Local Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes), nada impede a continuação de filtros, ordenações, junção de tabelas, etc. esses dois meios são para facilitar a não repetição de código, padronizando e auxiliando no desenvolvimento e manutenção do código.*