# Limitar relação por atributo comum

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou trabalhando no Laravel e tenho 3 tabelas (users, administracoes e imoveis).

Gostaria de saber, qual seria a melhor forma de relacionar (associar) usuários e imóveis que pertençam a mesma administração ?

Qual seria a melhor maneira de separar eles por administração, por um middleware e rotas, com uma simples função? Ou seja, como faço para os usuários que tenham o mesma id de administração vejam somente os imóveis que também tenham esse id de administração ?

Abaixo está a estrutura das minhas models e seus actuais relacionamentos:

Model Administração:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Painel;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;

class AdministracaoComunal extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'administracoes_comunais';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nome'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;


    // Relacionamnto OneToMany (os usuarios que estão vinculados a uma administracao)
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }

    // Relacionamnto OneToMany (os imoveis que estão vinculados a uma administracao)
    public function imoveis()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Imovel::class, 'administracao_comunal_id');
    }
}
```

Model User:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Models\Painel\AdministracaoComunal;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function administracaoComnunal(){
        return $this->belongsTo(AdministracaoComunal::class);
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Role::class);
    }

    public function hasPermission(Permission $permission)
    {
        return $this->hasAnyRoles($permission->roles);
    }

    public function hasAnyRoles($roles)
    {
        // Se tiver mais de um papel cai nesse loop
        if (is_array($roles) || is_object($roles)) {
            return !! $roles->intersect($this->roles)->count();
        }
        // Se tiver um papel retorna diretamente aqui
        return $this->roles->contains('funcao', $roles);
    }
}
```

Model Imovel:

```
<?php namespace App\Models\Painel;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;

class Imovel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'imoveis';

    protected $fillable = [
        'matricula',
        'finalidade',
        'tipo_imovel',
        'qtd_comodos',
        'largura',
        'comprimento',
        'longitude',
        'latitude',
        'provincia',
        'municipio',
        'distrito_comuna',
        'bairro',
        'rua',
        'n_casa',
        'numero_escritura',
        'data_criacao',
        'situacao_licenca',
        'situacao_ocupacao',
        'valor_imovel',
        'valor_aluguel',
        'valor_patrimonial',
        'administracao_comunal_id',
    ];

    public function administracaoComunal()
    {
        //
        return $this->belongsTo(AdministracaoComunal::class, 'administracao_comunal_id');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        //
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_imovel');
    }

    public function proprietarioSingular()
    {
        //
        return $this->belongsToMany(ProprietarioSingular::class, 'imovel_proprietario_singular');
    }

    public function proprietarioColetivo()
    {
        //
        return $this->belongsToMany(ProprietarioColetivo::class, 'imovel_proprietario_coletivo');
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dê uma lida: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148776/para-que-serve-um-scope-no-laravel/151866#151866 acredito ser isso que precisa?

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela indicação, dei uma lida lá e acredito que não satisfaça o meu caso, pois eu preciso limitar o acesso dos usuários por administração, assim como para os imóveis

Comment: A sua pergunta sugere esse comportamento, onde na SQL já decida quem é o usuário e o imovel, agora é muito ampla eu mesmo particularmente não entendi

Comment: Todos usuários estão conseguindo gerir todos os imóveis que eu cadastro, e não deve  ser assim,  eles só devem gerir os imóveis da administração a que pertencem. Confesso que a pergunta é bastante ampla sim, por isso eu mesmo não consigo achar o melhor forma de implementar essa separação.

Comment: Todos os usuários gerindo coisas que não pertence! primeira pergunta nas tabelas de imoveis tem o id da administração e o usuário tem como saber qual é sua administração? ou até alguma tabela que geri as duas informações?

Comment: a tabela imóveis tem o id da administração e o usuário também tem o id da administração a que está afectado

Comment: As suas relações me parece erradas, faz o seguinte disponibilize o diagrama das tabelas envolvidas! porque se tem que fazer duas coisas listar imoveis por usuario/administração e criar um middleware para bloquear também os dados que podem ser digitados por exemplo na url e acessar imoveis que não pertence o seu problema é amplo

Comment: Por hora não tenho como disponibilizá-lo, assim que puder envio. Mas resumidamente é assim: esses usuários na verdade são funcionários das várias administrações, e eles é que cadastram, editam e eliminam imóveis. Estes não podem gerir imóveis que não estão não pertencem as suas administrações. Então basicamente as relações que criei foram: 1 usuário pertence a uma administração, a administração por sua vez tem N usuários. E 1 imóvel pertence a uma administração, a mesma tem N imóveis

Comment: Correto, mas, não tem como ajudar se a sua pergunta não contiver mais detalhes. Ok!

Comment: acabei por adicionar o diagrama todo mas o foco é na parte das restrições mesmo

Comment: Realmente o problema é amplo, tem relações com municipios, desculpa mas, isso é uma grande duvida ...!

Comment: Está bem. Sim sei disso, mas a minha dúvida é relativa a parte das restrições dos usuários, porque o resto já está funcionando. Obrigado desde já pelo esforço  @Virgilio Novic