# Ticket médio de vendas usando AVG Laravel

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou tentando calcular o valor médio das vendas de uma loja porém estou enfrentando alguns problemas no calculo do valor total de cada venda, segue o código

Controller:

```
$valor_total = PedidoProdutos::with('valor_por_pedido')->get();
```

Model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PedidoProdutos extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pedido_produtos';
    protected $fillable = [
        'pedido_id', 'produto_id', 'valor', 'quantidade'
    ];


    public function pedido()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Pedido::class, 'pedido_id', 'id');
    }

    public function valor_por_pedido()
    {
        return $this->selectRaw('pedido_id, SUM(valor * quantidade) as total')
            ->groupBy('pedido_id');
    }

    public function media_de_vendas()
    {
        return $this->valor_por_pedido()->avg('total');
    }

}
```

Erro:

> `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addEagerConstraints()`

Comment: essa busca sua no mysql ta errada

Comment: pedido_produtos. não esta faltando no pedido_id,

Comment: mesmo deixando somente groupBy('pedido_id') continua com o mesmo erro

Comment: Carlos está errado alguma coisa, tem como colocar o seu model completamente? porque o primeiro código não é tem nada a ver com o segundo? acho ! que falta um relacionamento.

Comment: sempre que usar o 'pedido_produtos.' coloca ele em todo o código e melhor ou retira de todos

Comment: pronto, coloquei o model completo

Comment: Carlos isso não pode: `PedidoProdutos::with('valor_por_pedido')->get();` porque valor_por_pedido é um query Builder não é um relação!

Comment: Você pode trabalhar com scope! nesse caso, se está utilizando a tecnica errada !!! acho eu!

Comment: Sim, estava de fato confundindo as coisas kkkk, coloquei a query direto no controller mesmo e deu certo, valeu pessoal...

Comment: Se pode criar um scope e chamar como um método! é um boa! exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148776/para-que-serve-um-scope-no-laravel/151866#151866